# Reactjs and typescript assign randomly generated variable to div style width and height

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, styles

i am trying to assign randomly generated variable as width and height to div, so far i have written the function for generating random size but i get error when i'm trying to assign it to style

my goal is to generate new div everytime button is clicked

this is so far what i have written, i get error on :

```
style={{width:divSize}}
```

which says:

```
Variable 'divSize' is used before being assigned.ts(2454)
```

```
 function createRandomRectangle(){
  if (boxxy!=null) {
    var divSize = Math.round(((Math.random()*200) + 50));
    const width = boxxy.offsetWidth , height =boxxy.offsetHeight;
    var posX = Math.round((Math.random() * ( width- divSize)));
    var posY = Math.round((Math.random() * (  height- divSize)));
  }
  return(
    <div className='Rectangle' style={{width:divSize}}></div>
  )
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the divSize Before the if

```
function createRandomRectangle() {
let divSize;
if (boxxy!=null) {
divSize = Math.round(((Math.random()*200) + 50));
const width = boxxy.offsetWidth , height =boxxy.offsetHeight;
var posX = Math.round((Math.random() * ( width- divSize)));
var posY = Math.round((Math.random() * (  height- divSize)));
```